# docker-compose no refleja los paquetes de node_modules en mi local

Tags: javascript, nodejs, docker, docker-compose

El problema es el siguiente mi imagen se crea correctamente y se levanta igual. En el contenedor todos los paquetes de node_modules están pero no se ven reflejados en mi entorno local. La cual al abrir el editor me marca error.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10.16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i --quiet

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD npm run dev
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  work-today-api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9229:9229"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro básicamente le estabas diciendo con el docker-compose que mantuviera sus propios archivos de node_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este [post](https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190305/1953.html) me dio la solución a mi problema ya funciona correctamente.

Mi archivo `docker-compose.yml` quedo asi.

```
version: '2'
services:
  work-today-api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9229:9229"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    command: bash -c "npm run dev"
```